# Openssl accessor function to retrieve sig_alg from opaque struct X509_REQ

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

I am trying to update to OpenSSL 1.1.1 from 1.0.2 and in doing so I have to convert some code. A lot of structures were made opaque in 1.1.0 and now need an accessor function. For the most part I have found something that works or a suitable workaround. However I can't seem to find any accessor function(s) or suitable way to convert the following code snippet from my code:

```
OBJ_obj2nid(request->sig_alg->algorithm)
```

Where "request" is a  "X509_req_st" struct(in openssl typedefed to X509_REQ) and I want to access the sig_alg as seen in the openssl struct definition:

```
struct X509_req_st {
    X509_REQ_INFO req_info;     /* signed certificate request data */
    X509_ALGOR sig_alg;         /* signature algorithm */
    ASN1_BIT_STRING *signature; /* signature */
    CRYPTO_REF_COUNT references;
    CRYPTO_RWLOCK *lock;

    /* Set on live certificates for authentication purposes */
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *distinguishing_id;
};
```

And then access the algorithm as seen in the openssl X509_ALGOR struct definition

```
struct X509_algor_st {
   ASN1_OBJECT *algorithm;
   ASN1_TYPE *parameter;
};
```

I've have looked through the openssl project on github and especially the [x509.h.in](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/746f3674896845460946ace7e963e52b547fbf35/include/openssl/x509.h.in) file where most of the accessor functions seem to be found as well as scoured the web but can't find how to do this. If there is no accessor function that can do this I'll greatly appreciate any suggestions on how I could approach this or perhaps how/where to .patch in my own accessor function.

Comment: See line 714, or even better for your case line 718. Documentation should be on your system if you have OpenSSL installed suitable for compiling apps (e.g. in most Linuxes a package named something like openssl-dev) and also at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_REQ_get0_signature.html (one man page covers X509 X509_REQ and X509_CRL so focus on the right parts).

Comment: @dave_thompson_ I used function on row 718 (int X509_REQ_get_signature_nid(const X509_REQ *req)) like you said and it seems like it did the trick with just that one function now. Simple and clear, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `X509_REQ_get_signature_nid` to get the signature algorithm field. Internally, it is implemented using `OBJ_obj2nid` to the same member.
The equivalent function for X509 struct is also available in 1.0.2, but not the X509_REQ one.

So, in your case, the code should be:

```
int nid = X509_REQ_get_signature_nid(request)
```

You can refer this link for info:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_REQ_get_signature_nid.html